# Microsoft learn Kubernetes tutorial help for Mac

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, minikube

I am going through this tutorial "[Deploy .Net Microservices to Kubernetes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dotnet-deploy-microservices-kubernetes/)" in my Mac and got struck in [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/dotnet-deploy-microservices-kubernetes/4-exercise-deploy-to-kubernetes). I installed Minikube in my mac and I can see my frontend and backend containers are deployed in my local Kubernetes and running as below:

[image: >kubectl get all]

But I am not able to access either the frontend or the backend even with `https://localhost:<portnumber>` or the IP address my local Kubernetes is running on. I also tried changing my frontend service type from LoadBalancer to NodePort. But, it didn't help me with my page-not-found issue.

Initially, when I ran "kubectl apply" command, I was getting this error "[The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/the-connection-to-the-server-localhost-8080-was-refused-did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port/1464)", then followed the steps in the link, and installed Minikube. This did help me to run the kubectl apply commands.

The deployment yml files are there in the above step link and the tutorial link has repo URL. When I access http://localhost, the page is not found. What can I try next?

Comment: I’d check first what driver your minikube is using and then I’d try to connect to the front end by the node port port 30… something. If that doesn’t work check the minikube service command and put your front end service name in the command. It should point you how you can connect to it

Comment: I tried minikube service command and it opened up the browser with an external address but the same service port number 30*** but it didn't help me too. Thanks for your response. I will keep looking into and update when I find something.

Comment: After spending some time, I figured out that I need to run "minikube tunnel" and I could access my frontend by http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost

I followed the official documentation [here][1] but my output seems to be incomplete

[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCLNo.png